# Action for "don't allow" in the location permision?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, gps, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

If the user presses "Don't allow" when Core Location asking the permission, what is the method which would fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is right here in stackoverflow. [The answer from willi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333344/how-to-handle-dont-allow-for-location-manager)