# server did not accept client registration 68

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an app currently deployed on the app store. Just a few days ago, it stopped working all of a sudden. I am receiving the following error within xcode when testing my application.

server did not accept client registration 68

I am using xcode 4.1. I have read about this error online and seen the workarounds. My issue is that my application was running fine. No issues whatsoever. It literally just ceased to load data all of a sudden a few days ago. No updates were pushed, no code was modified. How is it possible for it to jus stop working all of a sudden? Could it be an update with Apple?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info to go on in your question, but by doing a search on the error message, it might be related to CoreLocation.

Has your App for whatever reason be set to not use location services (within the Settings app), real device or simulator? If so, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333344/how-to-handle-dont-allow-for-location-manager/2333736#2333736) on how to handle it nicely in code using didFailWithError